# Create exe file to Run npm commands

Tags: node.js, reactjs, command, exe

I want to run my react app and node app parallely by clicking on single .exe file. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do it by creating a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new text file and write your path and command lines to file; *e.g.*

```
cd C:\your-project-path
npm start
```

Then save it with .bat extension *(e.g. startmyapp.bat)*
So click and it will run.

if you want to run it on startup automatically, you can put this bat file to startup folder of windows.
mine is here:
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup